# Plotting of dot points based on np.where condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have a lot of data points (in .CSV form) that I am trying to visualize, what I would like to do is to read the csv and read the "result" column, if the value in the corresponding column is positive(I was trying to use np.where condition), I would like to plot the A B C D E F G parameters corresponding to it in such a way that the y-axis is the value of the parameters and x-axis is the name of the parameter.(Something like a dot/scatter plot) I would like to plot all the values in the same graph, Furthermore, if the number of points are more than 20 I would like to use the first 20 points for the plotting.

An example of the type of dataset is below. (Mine contains around 12000 rows)

```
  A    B     C   D     E   F   G   result
 23  -54    36   27   98  39  80   -0.86
 14   44   -16   47   28  29  26    1.65
 67   84    26   67  -88  29  10    0.5
-45   14    76   37   68  59  90    0
 24   34    56   27   38  79  48   -1.65
```

Any help in guiding for this would be appreciated !

Comment: Could you add a minimal version of your best-effort code? Could you also explain with a bit more detail what exactly is needed?  E.g. what is "amplitude"? How to interpret the 8 columns? Do you want to plot 12000 points?

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for replying, I will edit it with my best effort code , but its not that good and has errors now. By amplitude I meant the values of the Parameters A, B .... G , I have around 12000 results and Parameters corresponding to it, but I only want to plot the first 20 "results" that fulfill the criteria that "result should be greater that zero", If the "result" column has a value greater than zero we plot it , else we ignore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I assume that your data is a pandas dataframe. In this case you can do the selection with pandas and use its built-in plotting function:

```
df.loc[df.result>0, df.columns[:-1]].T.plot(ls='', marker='o')
```

[image]

If you want to plot the first 20 rows only, just add `[:20]` (or better `.iloc[:20]`) to `df.loc`.

Comment: Thank you this could work, can you guide me on how I can change the input parameters to this for example if I decide to only plot A , B , D , F in the future how can I change the code without having to change the entire csv file.

Comment: to only plot A, B, D, F use  `df.loc[df.result>0, ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F']][:20].T.plot(ls='', marker='o')`. See [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for details on how to select columns.